# Is 'The weather is sunny today' considered a statement (Logic in Discrete Mathematics)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

In the intro to discrete mathematics we talked about a statement, which is a declarative sentence. Examples of correct such sentences are: 1+1 = 2, or Athens is the capital of Greece. On the contrary, x+1=2 and what time is it, are both NOT considered statements, as their answers are not a definite "YES or NO" type answers. What about 'The weather is nice today' sentence. This can be a yes or no, but not for everybody. Where can we categorize it then?

Comment: One other argument why the sentence may not be considered a statement in the logical sentence is that it depends on the utterance situation ("today" is time-relative, and this is considered outside the scope of ordinary logic).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can categorize it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic
In fact that's one the first examples given in Fuzzy Logic when one starts to get familiar with it.

So yeah, I think definitely it's not a statement with a clear YES/NO truth value i.e. it's not a statement from ***propositional logic***.